# Incrementing a dictionary across multiple strings - not using any import functions

Tags: python, string, dictionary, increment

I am trying to increment a dictionary in Python 3, counting the number of occurrences of certain characters in a string.

**I cannot use any import/count function to do so**, and must iterate through one character at a time. All other queries on here seem to use an import functionality to answer the questions.

So far I have a dictionary that doesnt count duplicate characters nor does it update when presented with a new string:

```
def IncrementalCount(counts, line, charList):  
  counts={}  
  for letter in charList:  
    if letter in line:  
      if letter in counts.keys():  
        counts[letter] += 1  
      else:  
        counts[letter] = 1  
      if letter not in line:  
        counts[letter] = 0  
  return counts  

counts = {}  
counts= IncrementalCount(counts,"{hello!{}","}{#")  
print(counts)  
counts= IncrementalCount(counts,"#Goodbye!}","}{#!@")  
print(counts)
```

current result

```
{'}': 1, '{': 1, '#': 0}  
{'}': 1, '{': 0, '#': 1, '!': 1, '@': 0}
```

desired result

```
{'}': 1, '{': 2, '#': 0}  
{'}': 2, '{': 2, '#': 1, '!': 1, '@': 0}
```

Any help would be really appreciated on what edits i need to make. I dont understand why my "counts[letter] +=1" doesnt count duplicate entries.

Comment: Well you only increment once if the character is *in* the `line`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def IncrementalCount(counts, line, charList):  
    
    for letter in charList:  
        counts[letter]=counts.get(letter,0)+line.count(letter)
    return counts

counts = {}  
counts= IncrementalCount(counts,"{hello!{}","}{#")  
print(counts)  
counts= IncrementalCount(counts,"#Goodbye!}","}{#!@")  
print(counts)
```

out put

> {'}': 1, '{': 2, '#': 0}
>
> {'}': 2, '{': 2, '#': 1, '!': 1, '@': 0}

Answer (score 3):

You iterate over every letter and test `if letter in line`, but you do *not* count the number of times it occurs in the output.

Nevertheless, you make things too complex, we can construct a dictionary by using `line.count(..)` instead and write this as list comprehension:

```
def IncrementalCount(line, charList):
    return { letter: line.count(letter) for letter in charList }
```

This then produces:

```
>>> IncrementalCount("{hello!{}","}{#")
{'}': 1, '{': 2, '#': 0}
>>> IncrementalCount("#Goodbye!}","}{#!@")
{'}': 1, '{': 0, '#': 1, '!': 1, '@': 0}
```

In case we wish to *increment* an existing dictionary, we can use:

```
def IncrementalCount(counts, line, charList):
    for letter in charList:
        counts[letter] += line.count(letter)
```

Or in case it is possible that not all keys are present, we can use for instane a `defaultdict` (which is usually a more compact and efficient way), or we can retrieve it

```
def IncrementalCount(counts, line, charList):
    for letter in charList:
        counts.setdefault(letter, 0)
        counts[letter] += line.count(letter)
```

Or we can use `.get(..)` to retrieve it with a default value, but usually a `defaultdict` is a better design decision here.

> **N.B.**: usually function names in Python are all lower case and underscores (`_`) are used for spaces, so here it would by Pythonic to name it `incremental_count`.
>
> **N.B.**: there exist more effective ways to count: right now we iterate through the entire string for every character.